# How to customize pandas pie plot with labels and legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

Tried plotting a pie chart using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'City': ['KUMASI', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'KUMASI', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA'], 'Building': ['Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial'], 'LPL': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Lgfd': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'NC', 'NC', 'C'], 'Location': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Hazard': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Inspection': ['NC', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'NC', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'Name': ['Zonal', 'In Prog', 'Tullow Oil', 'XGI', 'Food Factory', 'MOH', 'EV', 'CSD', 'Electroland'], 'Air Termination System': ['Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Early Streamer Emission', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Early Streamer Emission'], 'Positioned Using': ['Highest Points', 'Software', 'Software', 'Software', 'Highest Points', np.nan, np.nan, 'Rolling Sphere Method', 'Software']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colors = ['#ff9999','#66b3ff','#99ff99','#ffcc99']
data = df["Air Termination System"].value_counts().plot(kind="pie",autopct='%1.1f%%', radius=1.5, shadow=True, explode=[0.05, 0.05], colors=colors)
```

Present chart looks like:

[image]

How do I bring the title "Air Termination Systems" outside the chart and also create a legend at the top right using the colors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `legend=True` adds the legend
- `title='Air Termination System'` puts a title at the top
- `ylabel=''` removes `'Air Termination System'` from inside the plot. The label inside the plot was a result of `radius=1.5`
- `labeldistance=None` removes the other labels since there is a legend.
- If necessary, specify `figsize=(width, height)` inside [`data.plot(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
colors = ['#ff9999','#66b3ff','#99ff99','#ffcc99']
data = df["Air Termination System"].value_counts()
ax = data.plot(kind="pie", autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, explode=[0.05, 0.05], colors=colors, legend=True, title='Air Termination System', ylabel='', labeldistance=None)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]